# Bootstrap - Different CSS rule for different grid prefix

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I building a mobile site with bootstrap, I would like to set different CSS rule to different grid prefix: col-xs , col-sm

HTML code sample:

```
<header class="col-xs col-sm">
   Hi
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header.col-md{
    background-color:red;   
}

header.col-sm{
    background-color:green;
}
```

any advise how to do it right?

Comment: simplest way is add the !important suffix at the end of the css eg header.col-md{
    background-color:red !Important;   
} (just ensure your css is loaded after the bootstrap css for it to be the winner. Maybe a better way but that is the simplest (doesn't mean the best)

Comment: You would use media queries and not use !important anywhere if at all possible. Re: !important, use CSS specificity to avoid it.

Comment: this go for two prefix, if you add third one: col-md?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.col-xs`, `.col-sm`, `.col-md` and `.col-lg` ARE NOT Bootstrap classes. The `.navbar` in bootstrap is their header component and it's already responsive.

To create your own classes that work as you envision, you would use your classes inside media queries, but the .col-xs would not be inside a media query (this assumes that the breakpoints have not changed from the Bootstrap 3.x defaults):

```
header.col-xs {styles}

@media (min-width:768px) {

  header.col-sm {styles}

}

@media (min-width:992px) {

  header.col-md {styles}

}

@media (min-width:1200px) {

  header.col-lg {styles}

}
```

It would be better, since a header is not a column, to change this to `.header-xs`, `.header-sm`, `.header-md`, `.header-lg`. Or you can just not use it at all and design your header with media queries and not even use a size associated class on it.

```
.header { base header styles shared by all viewport widths }

    @media (min-width:768px) {

      .header {styles such as floats or different from the base }

    }
```

*and so on...*

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a more specific selector, like id

```
<header id="my-header" class="col-xs col-sm">
   Hi
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#my-header.col-md{
    background-color:red;   
}

#my-header.col-sm{
    background-color:green;
}
```

It should beat bootstrap's selector specificity and the browser will use yours.

Read more about specificity: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/